# How to use TortoiseGit to perform the git command `git reset --hard origin/master`?

Tags: tortoisegit

I have this scenario when use TortoiseGit.

A use the `Reset master to this...` to revert some changes and force pushed to the remote refs master.

B pull the code and said `Already up-to-date`. And use the show log said the local master is before `origin/master`.

I know using the git command `git reset --hard origin/master` will fix this for me.

I would like to know how to overidde local master with remote origin/master using TortoiseGit?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch in the log to `remotes/origin/master`

All the steps:

1. Fetch
2. Switch to `master`
3. Go to log
4. On the left upper side, select `remotes/origin/master` :

   [image]
5. Do `reset "master" to this` , en then "hard"

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I know this method. Is there any more convenient way as I need to teach other teammate do this?  ^-^